# SQL Cascading Join

Tags: sql, join

I have the following join as part of a View:

```
from studies
inner join orders on orders.orderId = studies.orderId
    left outer join referrers on referrers.referrerId = orders.referrerId
        left outer join professionalDegrees referrerDegree on referrerDegree.professionalDegreeId = referrers.professionalDegreeId
```

referrers.professionalDegreeId column is NOT NULL. In queries that are limited to the referrers scope, the JOIN to professionalDegrees is INNER.

In the View above, if I INNER JOIN on professionalDegrees, there are no rows returned where orders.referrerId is NULL. When I LEFT JOIN on professionalDegrees the row is returned with NULL referrerId, as desired.

Does INNER vs LEFT matter to performance in this case? Is there a better way to write this JOIN?